# Including ros into scons project

Tags: ros, ros2, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have built ros from sources (specifically ros2 bouncy bolson).
The result is that I have a workspace containing all the header and lib files.

Now I would like to write a ros node inside a project which is built using Scons.
How should I include and link properly all the required stuffs?

My program is just an hello world which includes the C++ client library

```
#include <iostream>
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::cout<<"Hello World!"<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Sconstruct file

```
 env = Environment()
 env.Append(CXXFLAGS = ['-std=c++14'])
 env.Append(CPPPATH = ['<PATH_TO_ROS2_WS>/install/rclcpp/include', .....])
 env.Append(LIB_PATH=['<PATH_TO_ROS2_WS>/install/rclcpp/lib', ....])
 env.Program("hello_ros", ["hello_ros.cpp"])
```

I tried to manually append one by one to the environment the path  to ROS2 include dirs and library locations.

UPDATE:
I was getting an error due to the CXXFLAGS set to c++11, ROS2 requires C++14.

Is there a way to let Scons find the ROS2 include and library files, instead of having to manually specify them (they are a lot if I'm not using the --merge-install flag during the ros2 build)?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301295/including-ros-into-scons-project/) by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1322 on 2018-08-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pokitoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32070/pokitoz/) on 2018-08-23**:
When you say nothing is working, can you paste the error message? I guess it is a linkage error but maybe it is something different. You will need to include all libraries/includes from ROS2 (at least the one that RCLCPP depends on).

**Comment by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on 2018-08-23**:
Hi, thanks for your help but I solved that error. I have still an issue due to the fact that I have to manually specify all the lib and include paths (they are a lot if I'm not using the --merge-install flag during the ros2 build)

**Comment by [pokitoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32070/pokitoz/) on 2018-08-24**:
I don't think there is another solution to adding all the lib/include paths to your build. (unfortunately :D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have no knowledge about `scons`, but the following might be helpful whatever you want to integrate ROS 2 packages into:

`ament_cmake` packages automatically generate CMake config files. You can query the information provided by those through the CMake command line tool.

The compiler arguments required to build against a specific ROS 2 can be queries with:

> `cmake --find-package -DNAME=rclcpp -DCOMPILER_ID=GNU -DLANGUAGE=CXX -DMODE=COMPILE`

The linker arguments can be retrieved with a similar command:

> `cmake --find-package -DNAME=rclcpp -DCOMPILER_ID=GNU -DLANGUAGE=CXX -DMODE=LINK`

If you depend on multiple package you will have to query the arguments for each of them.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on 2018-08-24**:
Thanks! However it works with other packages (i.e. boost), but with rclcpp I get an error:
Generator implementation error, all generators must specify this->FindMakeProgramFile
CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Generic"
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-08-24**:
The posted command lines do work for me on Ubuntu Bionic with a locally built workspace (haven't tried any other combinations but would expect them to work too).

**Comment by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on 2018-08-24**:
Ok thank you. I tested it on a Bionic Docker container and it works. The error is on Ubuntu Xenial